# UICollectionView Sections Overlapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm having an issue whereby objects in my collection view collide with and interact with one another unintentionally.

**Explanation:**

I have a UICollectionView that I'm populating with custom UICollectionViewCell objects. This all works fine and well. I've also got headers to separate each section.

Now, one of the basic functionality of these buttons is to have an off state, and an on state.

The problem, though, is that when I turn a button "on" to something in my first section, it turns "on" or "off" a button in my last section, which appears off screen. In addition, the section titles sort of overlap as well.
[image]

Here is the code that generates each cell:

**Custom Cell class**

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.tagBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.tagBtn.frame = CGRectMake(-frame.size.width/4+20, -frame.size.width/4+15, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
        [[self.tagBtn layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0f/255.0f green:99.0f/255.0f blue:74.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor]];
        [[self.tagBtn layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        self.tagBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.tagBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0f/255.0f green:99.0f/255.0f blue:74.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.tagBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
        [self.tagBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleTag) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.tagBtn];

    }

    return self;
}
```

**Cell data source delegate**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TagCellCollectionViewCell *cell = (TagCellCollectionViewCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *data = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    // Configure the cell

    NSString *labelText = data[indexPath.row];

    [cell.tagBtn setTitle:labelText forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return cell;
}
```

**Button toggle method**

```
- (void) toggleTag {
    if (self.tagBtn.backgroundColor == [UIColor whiteColor]) {
        self.tagBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:234.0f/255.0f green:99.0f/255.0f blue:74.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        [self.tagBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
        self.tagBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.tagBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0f/255.0f green:99.0f/255.0f blue:74.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

**Section titles**

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        UICollectionReusableView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"Header" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (headerView == nil) {
            headerView = [[UICollectionReusableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 320, 25)];
        }

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 320, 25)];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %li", indexPath.section];
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:38.0f/255.0f green:34.0f/255.0f blue:108.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
        headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0f/255.0f green:204.0f/255.0f blue:222.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        [headerView addSubview:label];
        return headerView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

**Is there anything else you'd like to see?**

**UPDATE**

New button code with answer below

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TagCellCollectionViewCell *cell = (TagCellCollectionViewCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *data = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    // Configure the cell

    NSString *labelText = data[indexPath.row];

    [cell.tagBtn setTitle:labelText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.tagBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.tagBtn.tag = indexPath.row + 1000*indexPath.section;


    if (self.toggledIndexPath == indexPath) {
        cell.tagBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:234.0f/255.0f green:99.0f/255.0f blue:74.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        [cell.tagBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
        cell.tagBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [cell.tagBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0f/255.0f green:99.0f/255.0f blue:74.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    return cell;
}

- (void) toggleTag:(UIButton *) btn {
    NSIndexPath *path;
    if (btn.backgroundColor == [UIColor whiteColor]) {
        path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:btn.tag/1000 inSection:btn.tag % 1000];
    }else{
        path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:-1 inSection:0];
    }
    self.toggledIndexPath = path;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: You need to show the button method. It's clear from what you have in cellForItemAtIndexPath, that you're not dealing with cell reuse properly.

Comment: Much appreciated. I'm new to collection views and this depth of customization in general. Which method would you be referring to exactly? I've got the cell generator and the custom cell declaration in there where the button is actually added.

Comment: The button's action method, toggleTag is the one I mean. Since you're also having trouble with your section titles, you should show how you're creating those as well.

Comment: Edited the code to show the toggleTag method as well as the section titles

Comment: You are adding the header label to your header view every time it's loaded. Try changing the code to add it only on the first load, then update the label text on subsequent loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems having to do with cell and header view reuse. Any changes that you make to the cell's UI should be done inside cellForItemAtIndexPath, not outside like in your button's action method. If you do it in the action method, then when that cell is reused, the button will still have those changed values, but now in a different position in the collection view. You need to get the indexPath for the cell where you touched the button. There are several ways to do that, the easiest of which is to give your button a tag based on the indexPath (when you have sections, you need to use both, something like button.tag = indexPath.row + 1000*indexPath.section). In the button's action method, you should just set some property in your data source that indicates the button at a particular indexPath should have its properties changed, and then change them in an if-else clause in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TagCellCollectionViewCell *cell = (TagCellCollectionViewCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *data = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSString *labelText = data[indexPath.row];
    [cell.tagBtn setTitle:labelText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.tagBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.tagBtn.tag = indexPath.row + 1000*indexPath.section;
    if (self.toggledIndexPath == indexPath) {
        cell.tagBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:234.0f/255.0f green:99.0f/255.0f blue:74.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        [self.tagBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else {
        cell.tagBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [cell.tagBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0f/255.0f green:99.0f/255.0f blue:74.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void) toggleTag:(UIButton *) btn {
    if (self.tagBtn.backgroundColor == [UIColor whiteColor]) {
        indexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:btn.tag % 1000 inSection:btn.tag/1000];
    }else{
        indexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:-1 inSection:0];
    }
    self.toggledIndexPath = path;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Notice that I added the button's action method in cellForRowAtIndexPath rather than in the button's init method. toggledIndexPath is a property I added to keep track of which buttons was touched.

The problem with the section titles, is that you're adding multiple labels to your headerView, because when viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind is called and it has a cell to reuse, you're still adding a label to it. You should either create your view in a xib, or add any subviews in the init method for the view (if you're doing everything in code). The only thing you should be doing in viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind, is to set the title and return the view.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. Reuse is where my head starts to break down. I'll give your suggestions a try when I get back on this project again and let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: So I made the updates you suggested to the buttons, and I've put the code in my question, but now the buttons don't toggle at all. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Zarathuztra, Sorry, I had the math wrong in the button method. Switch the btn.tag/1000 and the tag % 1000. I've updated my answer to show the correct code.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, just couldn't wrap my head around the changes, I"ll give it a try tonight. Thanks!

Comment: @rdelmer Everything works fine now, except that when I tap one button, the highlight moves away from another. The goal is to be able to tab and highlight as many buttons as I want, not just one at a time. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Zarathuztra, yes, instead of a property to hold a single indexPath, you need to have a mutable array property, that you add indexPaths to. Instead of comparing the indexPath to toggledIndexPath, you'll have to use containsObject: on the array to see if it contains a particular indexPath.

Comment: I'll need to manage removing objects from that array as well, right?

Comment: @Zarathuztra, yes if you want to de-select a cell if you click it when it's already selected.

Answer (score 2):

Collection View Section Overlapping problem solve this code

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {


        UICollectionReusableView *reusableview=nil;
        reusableview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSArray *viewsToRemove = [reusableview subviews];
        for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }
        if (reusableview==nil) {
            reusableview=[[UICollectionReusableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 30)];
        }
        reusableview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0/255.0 green:234.0/255.0 blue:234.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

        UILabel *lblTitle=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-90, 30)];
        [lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu-Light" size:12]];

        lblTitle.textColor=HTAtHomeColor;
        [reusableview addSubview:lblTitle];

        UILabel *lblCount=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-80, 0, 70, 30)];
        lblCount.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
        lblCount.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [lblCount setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu-Light" size:12]];

        if (indexPath.section==0){
            lblCount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Selected",(long)mealTypeCount];
            lblTitle.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MEAL TYPE"];
        }
        else if (indexPath.section==1){
            lblCount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Selected",(long)mealOfDayCount];
            lblTitle.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MEAL OF THE DAY"];
        }
        else if (indexPath.section==2){
            lblCount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Selected",(long)cuisineCount];
            lblTitle.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TYPES OF CUSINE"];
        }

        [reusableview addSubview:lblCount];

        return reusableview;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: What if we have a UICollectionReusableView implementation using XIB? I am facing same issue of overlapping in XIB implementation.